# Can't send twitter post from Google Apps Script

Tags: twitter, oauth, google-apps-script

I'm new to Google Apps Script and I'm trying to post in Twitter from my script, but every time I get this error when I run the script:

> You do not have access to library OAuth1, used by your script, or it has been deleted.

I've added `TwtrService` in libraries and selected latest version `15`. Here is my code:

```
    function main()
    {
        var TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY     = "MY_KEY";
        var TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET  = "MY_SECRET";
        
        ScriptProperties.setProperty("TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY",    TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY);
        ScriptProperties.setProperty("TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET", TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET);
        login();
        tweet("Hi there from Google Apps Script");
    }
    
    
    function login()
    {
        var loginConfig = UrlFetchApp.addOAuthService("twitter");
        loginConfig.setAccessTokenUrl("https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token");
        loginConfig.setRequestTokenUrl("https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token");
        loginConfig.setAuthorizationUrl("https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize");
        loginConfig.setConsumerKey(ScriptProperties.getProperty("TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY"));
        loginConfig.setConsumerSecret(ScriptProperties.getProperty("TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET"));
    }
    
    function tweet(text)
    {
        var params =
        {
            "method": "POST",
            "oAuthServiceName":"twitter",
            "oAuthUseToken":"always"        
        };
        var status =  "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json";
        status = status + "?status=" + text;
        try
        {
            var success = UrlFetchApp.fetch(status, params);
            Logger.log(success.getContentText());
        }
        catch(ex)
        {
            Logger.log(ex.toString()); 
        }
    }
```

How to resolve this problem? How to get access to library OAuth1?

Answer (score 1):

Apps Script no longer supports the "oAuthServiceName" method for OAuth.  The new way has a different API, which involves creating a new OAuth1 object (provided by the library referenced in [Amit Agarwal's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34438401/3089006), and using that to fetch rather than calling `UrlFetchApp.fetch` directly.  The code would look something like

```
function login() {
  return OAuth1.createService("twitter")
    .setPropertyStore(PropertiesService.getScriptProperties())
    .setAccessTokenUrl("https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token")
    .setRequestTokenUrl("https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token")
    .setAuthorizationUrl("https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize")
    .setConsumerKey(ScriptProperties.getProperty("TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY"))
    .setConsumerSecret(ScriptProperties.getProperty("TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET"));
}

function tweet(text) {
  var oauth = login();
  var status =  "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json";
  oauth.fetch(status + "?status=" + text, {method : "POST"});
}
```

However, I would recommend using my Twitter lib for Apps Script, since it does much of the heavy lifting of setting up correct endpoints and queries for you. It builds on OAuth1, so while you still have direct access to `fetch()`, you can simply dump all of your config into ScriptProperties, call `new Twitterlib.OAuth(PropertiesService.getScriptProperties()).sendTweet(text);`, and the setup will be taken care of for you.

The key for Twitter Lib is MKvHYYdYA4G5JJHj7hxIcoh8V4oX7X1M_

Answer (score 0):

Go to the Google Script Editor and follow these instructions: ([source](https://github.com/googlesamples/apps-script-oauth1#setup))

1. Click on the menu item "Resources > Libraries..."
2. In the "Find a Library" text box, enter the project key and click the "Select" button.
   **Mb2Vpd5nfD3Pz-_a-39Q4VfxhMjh3Sh48**
3. Choose a version in the dropdown box (usually best to pick the
   latest version). Click the "Save" button.